# How to position elements in circle in right way with css

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have 10 elements which i need to position in circle so that means i need to use rotate. See below image to understand what am trying to achive

[image]

What i did so far is

```
<div class="game_wheel_item game_wheel_hundred_one">
      <img src="/images/wheel_numbers_bg.png" alt="wheel">
</div>
<div class="game_wheel_item game_wheel_hundred_two">
      <img src="/images/wheel_numbers_bg.png" alt="wheel">
</div>
```

And the css is

```
.game_wheel_item{
width: 37%;
float: left;
}
.game_wheel_hundred_one{
margin-top: 70px;
-ms-transform: rotate(-65deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-65deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-65deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-65deg);
transform: rotate(-65deg);
}
.game_wheel_hundred_two{
-ms-transform: rotate(-24deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-24deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-24deg);
transform: rotate(-24deg);
margin-left: -56px;
margin-top: 16px;
}
```

Any ideas how i can organize things so it fit in both widthwise/heightwise?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to use images for this?

Comment: Yes i ought to use images for the separate parts @JayStar

Comment: why dont you create a big circle within that big circle create a small circle which will be in the centre than put you images within the big circle just like the image above. The rotation will surely works for you.

Comment: I already did like that but it is not very dynamic as am using absolute positioning for the wheel items with top and left margin. So i wonder to find a dynamic/responsive solution for this @Jay Star.

Comment: Check this out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/placing-items-circle/ this will help you accomplish the image above. I hope this will do the trick.

Comment: Yeah i did something similar. I have 10 elements so i did a calculation 360 / 10 = 36 degree. SO i have all the wheel elements rotated by 36degree from teh second element, so third is 72 degree etc. Thanks for the reply @JayStar

Comment: okay. I hope you got it right.